# Iterate through an array with multiple dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-dictionary

So i used this line of code

```
if let image = test[0]["listing_images"] {
   let imagereceiver = image
   print(image)
}
```

to get listing_image from CondoIndivi2 and assign  to image receiver. Now imagereceiver   will  look like this  [image] As you can see it has dictionaries inside .I want to get the file_name that are in every dictionary  so that i can store those in my  var imageArray = [String:AnyObject]. 
Here is my code

```
     import UIKit
     import  Alamofire
     import SwiftyJSON
     import MapKit
     import CoreLocation

     class DetailsViewController: UIViewController , MKMapViewDelegate ,  CLLocationManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var Price: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Floor: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollerpage: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapview: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var bath: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bed_number: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var PhotoDetailsView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label5: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label6: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label7: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label8: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label9: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label10: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label11: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label12: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label13: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label14: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label15: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label16: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label17: UILabel!





@IBOutlet var descritpionlabel: UILabel!


var CondoIndivi2 = [[String:AnyObject]]()
var imageArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()
var test = [[String :AnyObject]]()
let adress : String = ""



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    scrollerpage.contentSize.height = 15000



    test = [
        [
            "id": 744736,
            "pic_count": 6,
            "mls_unique_id": 342947084,
            "list_price": 1480000,
            "property_type": "RE2",
            "city": "Miami",
            "bedrooms": 3,
            "bath": 3,
            "status": "A",
            "entry_date": "2016-02-11 00:11:52",
            "mls_number": "A10032455",
            "street_number": 1060,
            "street_directional":  "",
            "street_name": "Brickell",
            "city_id": 65,
            "zipcode": 33131,
            "address": "1060 Brickell # 4505",
            "primary_listing_pid": 3039955,
            "secondary_listing_pid": "",
            "municipal_code": 31,
            "township_number": 22,
            "section_number": 11,
            "subdivision_number":  "",
            "area": 41,
            "parcel_number": 1250,
            "year_built": 2009,
            "virtual_tour_link": "",
            "half_bath": 1,
            "living_area": 1933,
            "garage_spaces": 1,
            "waterfront": "Y",
            "total_area":  "",
            "pool":  "",
            "maintenance_fee": 1662,
            "pets_allowed": "Yes",
            "unit_number": 4505,
            "lot_area":  "",
            "listing_broker_code": "ZZON01",
            "listing_broker_office": "Zona",
            "latitude": 25.764026271539,
            "longitude": -80.191569328308,
            "original_list_price": 1780000,
            "main_photo_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/sefpic/large/342947084-1.jpg",
            "sale_price": 0,
            "days_on_market": 73,
            "close_date":  "",
            "selling_broker_code":  "",
            "expiration_date":  "",
            "condo_id": 444,
            "complex": "Avenue 1060 Brickell",
            "subdivision":  "",
            "community_name":  "",
            "lot_dimensions":  "",
            "hoa_fees":  "",
            "taxes": 32337,
            "tax_year": 2015,
            "rental_type":  "",
            "rental_occupancy": "Tenant Occupied",
            "rental_furnished": "U",
            "commercial_type":  "",
            "commercial_lease_sale":  "",
            "commercial_style":  "",
            "commercial_building":  "",
            "commercial_building_alt":  "",
            "county_id": "DADE",
            "selling_public_id":  "",
            "second_selling_public_id":  "",
            "agent_name": "Eduardo Diez",
            "broker_office_phone": "305-397-8192",
            "agent_phone": "305-753-1113",
            "second_agent_phone":  "",
            "second_agent_name":  "",                "parking_restrictions":  "",
            "condo_waterfront_view": [
            "No Fixed Bridges"
            ],
            "foreclosure":  "",
            "short_status":  "",
            "home_design":  "",
            "home_view": "Ocean View,Water View",
            "short_sale": "N",
            "reo": "N",
            "internet_address_ok":  "",
            "modified_date": "2016-02-11 00:44:48",
            "image_modified_date": "2016-02-11 00:23:16",
            "directions":  "",
            "property_style": "Condo 5+ Stories",
            "building_amenities": [
            "Elevator",
            "Exercise Room"
            ],
            "equipment": [
            "Automatic Garage Door Opener",
            "Circuit Breaker",
            "Dishwasher",
            "Dryer",
            "ELEVATOR",
            "Fire Alarm",
            "Microwave",
            "Refrigerator",
            "Self Cleaning Oven",
            "Smoke Detector"
            ],
            "exterior_features": [
            "High Impact Doors",
            "Open Balcony",
            "Other"
            ],
            "interior_features": [
            "Closets Cabinetry",
            "Cooking Island",
            "Handicap Equipped",
            "Other Interior Features",
            "Split Bedroom",
            "Vaulted Ceilings"
            ],
            "construction_type": [
            "Concrete Block Construction"
            ],
            "floors":  "",
            "roof_type": "",
            "home_heating": "",
            "pet_restriction": "Restrictions Or Possible Restrictions",
            "home_cooling": [
            "Central Cooling",
            "Electric Cooling",
            "Other"
            ],
            "home_design_2":  "",                "bedroom_2_size":  "",
            "bedroom_3_size":  "",
            "bedroom_4_size": "",
            "bedroom_master_size": "",
            "kitchen_size": "",
            "living_room_size":  "",
            "rental_includes":  "",
            "description": "Unique duplex apartment on brickell avenue. Amazing views. Building with all amenities. Walking distance to restaurants, bars, markets, convenient stores.",
            "rooms": "",
            "sewer":  "",
            "water":  "",
            "subdv":  "",
            "dinner":  "",
            "floor_location": "45<sup>th</sup>",
            "property_type_db": "RE2",
            "pets_icon": "Yes",
            "furnished_icon": "",
            "price_sqft": 765.64924987067,
            "price_sq_meters": 8241.6496218586,
            "living_area_meters": 179.5757,
            "price_change_days": 23,
            "price_change_type": -1,
            "price_change_diff": 300000,
            "price_change_percent": 20.27,
            "price_change_arrow": "down",
            "days_on_market_str": "2 months",
            "days_on_market_unix": 1455167512,
            "listing_images": [
            [
            "file_name": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/sefpic/large/342947084-1.jpg",
            "comments": "",
            "photo_id": 1
            ],
            [
            "file_name": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/sefpic/large/342947084-2.jpg",
            "comments": "",
            "photo_id": 2
            ],
            [
            "file_name": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/sefpic/large/342947084-3.jpg",
            "comments": "",
            "photo_id": 3
            ],
            [
            "file_name": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/sefpic/large/342947084-4.jpg",
            "comments": "",
            "photo_id": 4
            ],
            [
            "file_name": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/sefpic/large/342947084-5.jpg",
            "comments": "",
            "photo_id": 5
            ],
            [
            "file_name": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/sefpic/large/342947084-6.jpg",
            "comments": "",
            "photo_id": 6
            ]
            ],
            "permalink_url": "/property-view/1060-brickell---4505/miami/342947084/"
        ]
    ]





      let longtitude_map =   test[0]["longitude"] as! Double
      let latitude_map =   test[0]["latitude"]  as! Double
      let adress =  test[0]["address"]  as! String


      if let image = test[0]["listing_images"]{
      let imagereceiver = image
      print(imagereceiver )
       }

    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude_map, longtitude_map)

    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    mapview.setRegion(region, animated: false)





    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = location

    annotation.title = adress


    mapview.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("action:"))

    uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2

    mapview.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)











}








override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var result = [[String:AnyObject]]()

for item in test {
    result.append(["file_name":item["file_name"]])
}
```

Comment: test :Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType' thats what i m getting